# Make Evolve (DB Migration) Erase include all schemas

Tags: visual-studio-2017, database-migration, sql-server-2016, flyway, evolve

I'm using [Evolve](https://github.com/lecaillon/Evolve) which is based on Flyway for database migrations. When I create the database from scratch my migration scripts create schemas named `rls` and 'legacy', function and a procedure in `rls`, and a table in `legacy`.

When I set the Evolve command to `erase` to erase my database so that I can create it from scratch, it first fails because I have a couple security policies that depend on the tables that I guess Evolve can't detect. So I drop those myself and build my project again to run the Erase command and the output window shows:

```
4>  Executing Erase...
4>  Evolve initialized.
4>  Successfully erased schema dbo.
4>  Erase schema(s) completed: 1 erased, 0 skipped.
```

Notice it only mentions the schema dbo and doesn't even list the others as skipped. All of the objects in my database in the `dbo` schema are gone, but those in `rls` and `legacy` are still there including the schemas themselves. So if I now switch my command back to `migrate` to create the database from scratch, it's going to blow up when it tries to create these objects because they already exist. According to the documentation it's supposed to

> [erase] all the database objects (tables, views...) of the schemas
>   created by Evolve or found empty.

Why isn't it erasing them?

Comment: Just curious - why did you choose Evolve over Flyway itself (or ReadyRoll Core, if you use VS Enterprise)?

Comment: I'm new to the concepts and had < 0 hours to spend on it. We're not doing CI and Evolve looked like it had what we need and was easy to install and use. I wasn't able to quickly determine how to set up and start using Flyway with Windows & Visual Studio or if it would be too complicated for my small team. So long answer short: too steep of a learning curve.

Comment: Do you have VS Enterprise? If so, try ReadyRoll Core from the company I work for as this has deep VS integration if that's important to you.

Comment: That looks really nice. I've liked the red gate tools I've used in the past. I think I only have VS Professional. We're not doing CI right now so all I really need is the ability to keep each developer's local Db up to date and the ability to avoid collisions/conflicts when checking in a migration. I'm not sure how you accomplish the latter with ReadyRoll. With evolve we just sacrificed using a description in the file name and just name them all v1_X__migration.sql so that the file names will conflict to indicate a merge may be required.

Comment: So you are forcing a merge conflict in case there's duplication or dependency issues? This seems a little harsh. Could you instead allow the issue to occur and spot this when you try to execute the migrations? ReadyRoll benefits from continuous validation as it is always trying to build a "shadow" database in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the schema names in the call arguments like this:

```
.\evolve.exe -c "Host=10.10.10.10;Port=5432;Database=a;Username=a;Password=v;Enlist=true" -l .\db -s dbo -s rls -s legacy --metadata-table-schema migrations erase postgresql
```

Please note, that evolve is only able to erase schemas which were created by Evolve. Otherwise, you got this error:

```
This schema was not empty when Evolve first started migrations.
```

So you probably need to delete the "Create schema" commands from your commands and instead pass the names of the schemas to evolve, evolve will then create them for you.

Answer (score 0):

If Evolve marks it as empty then it can erase the database:

```
$ dotnet evolve migrate '@args.txt'
Executing Migrate...
Evolve initialized.
Mark schema public as empty. <-----------------------------  EMPTY 
No metadata found.
Successfully applied migration V1_1_1__CreateUser.sql in 244 ms.
Successfully applied migration V1_1_2__CreateProduct.sql in 67 ms.


$ dotnet evolve erase '@args.txt'
Evolve initialized.
Executing Erase...
Successfully erased schema public.
Erase schema(s) completed: 1 erased, 0 skipped.
```

**Note:** Delete manually the database if evolve did not mark as empty its public scheme.